# Delphi 10.2.3 and iOS 9

Tags: delphi, ios9

My Delphi shows the SDK as iPhoneOS 11.2.

My beta testers with iOS 9 are getting a TestFlight window that says:

> "Chess Openings Wizard" isn't compatible with this device.

How can I compile for iOS 9? And what are the drawbacks (if any) from supporting iOS 9?

Comment: Perhaps you're calling functions that are available only on iOS 10 and above? The best solution is to ensure that you're not doing that, and that the Minimum iOS version supported in the project options is not set higher than 9.0 (it defaults to 8.0). Why is there not more detail about what the *actual* problem is? Does "Won't run" mean not at all? Does a splash screen show? Any errors?

Comment: The "Minimum iOS Supported" is indeed set to 8.0.

What I have are reports from beta testers saying they get a message that the app doesn't run on this iPad.

Comment: Do you have the *exact* message?

Comment: I've just emailed two of the most recent testers asking for screen shots.

Comment: I updated the description. My beta testers (running iOS 9.3.5 on their iPads) are getting a TestFlight window that says: "Chess Openings Wizard" isn't compatible with this device.

Comment: In the Project Options, go to Version Info, and check that the UIDeviceFamily value says "iPhone & iPad". What model iPads are having problems? (needs the exact model number from Settings->General->About) As per zdichs answer, if they're older iPads they may not support 64-bit (if you're not providing a universal binary)

Comment: With wrong UIDeviceFamily the app would not run on any iPad device, regardless of the iOS version, but of course it should be also checked. I assume that there are many testers with many different iOS devices, and only iPads with iOS 9.3.5 are causing troubles - Mike, make it clear, please.

Comment: There are 177 beta testers using TestFlight to test this app. As far as I can tell, only users of iOS 9.5.3 are seeing this issue. My project did not have the checkbox checked for the universal binary. I checked that box, made a new build, and added it to TestFlight. I'm awaiting feedback from testers.

Comment: It does appear that the app is now running for testers on iOS 9.3.5 iPads. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Delphi 10.2.3 compiles and runs applications for iOS 9.3.5 without problems, even on iPads mini 1st generation with 32bit A5 processor. You can even use SDK 11.3 (with latest patch: https://cc.embarcadero.com/item/30835). Just remember to generate also 32bit version, i.e. set "project/options/Delphi compiler/compiling/Generate iOS universal binary file" to TRUE for 64bit iOS platform. You should see both iOSDevice32 and iOSDevice64 subfolders in your project folder after compile. In case of any troubles first Clean the project in project manager (in Delphi IDE), than manually delete the iOSDevice32/64 subfolders. Always run the app from the 64bit target, even for 32bit device.